# Reporting statistics in Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring, reporting, spring-webflow-2, web-statistics

We have an enterprise application using Spring 3.2.8 and Spring Web Flow 2.3.3 deployed on the Websphere 8 server. We wish to report statistics like no. of incomplete flows, the state at which user terminate the flow, time spent at individual states etc. We thought of using Spring Instrumentation. However, could not find instrumentation jar package for Spring 3.2 and Webflow 2.3. Where can I find the complete distribution of Spring 3.2 instrumentation jars? Or which other tool can I use for my purpose with Websphere 8? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a google search.  If I read the webpage correctly, instrumented spring is a paid product.

From http://static.springsource.com/projects/instrumentation/index.html:

> Instrumented Spring Framework, Web Services, Web Flow, and Security are available as part of a tc Server Spring Edition 2.x subscription or evaluation, which includes integration with Hyperic HQ. Instrumented Spring products are also available to Spring Enterprise subscribers.